# Which are the consequences of Uranus' high rotation axis angle?

Tags: rotation, uranus

The rotation axis of Uranus is 90 degrees away from vertical, [there are some theories about its reason.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-is-the-accepted-theory-as-to-why-uranus-axis-is-tilted-so-severely). But which are the consequences of this? Which are the unique features of Uranus that happened because of it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by consequences? In the broad sense a 'consequence' would be any effect with the axis angle as a cause (which is too broad). In the strict sense a 'consequence' would be a "bad" effect, and it is not clear in this case what would be "bad".

Comment: @called2voyage I mean, those features of Uranus that are uniqure for this planet (=none of the other planets have) and happened by the high rotation axis angle. No matter good of bad.

Comment: Right, that's what I referred to in the broad sense. I think that would be too broad, but I'll let others weigh in on it.

Comment: What specific consequences?  This could almost be a topic of the week with how many consequences there are.  To hop, a couple of suggestions to focus on - e.g. rotation of its moons, magnetic field interacting with other planets etc

Comment: @UV-D I asked in general. What does it mean for Uranus? How it is different than other planets?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt, then I think called2voyage is right, it is a bit broad - it could be separated into a couple of very good questions.