# Why does Venus spin so slowly?

Tags: venus

From my research it doesn't appear to be from tidal locking with the sun.

Is there somewhere I can start reading about the probable causes?

Comment: This question contains some of the hypothesized causes, however doesn't contain links to references.  It might help point you in the right direction, though: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-the-current-accepted-theory-as-to-why-venus-has-a-slow-retrograde-rotati?rq=1

Comment: Tidal locking with the sun may be why it spins slowly, that is, assuming it spun faster in the past (nobody knows).   Some good answers to the same question here:  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/why-is-the-rotation-rate-of-venus-so-slow  as for where to start looking, a quick google search gave me a number of solid articles.    Keep in mind, it's generally agreed that nobody knows, but google would be a place to start for some solid (and probably some wacky) theories.

Comment: Why not? What did your research effort so far reveal?

Comment: Because it's fat.